# Will my existing Zumo token base authentication and authorization work as it it in Azure mobile app node backend?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Currently we are using Azure mobile services with Node backend.As we all know that Azure is already stopped support of creating new Azure mobile services and they are suggesting to Migrate and/or Upgrade options to move existing Mobile services to app services.So we have choosen Migration steps to convert our Mobile Service Node backend to app service node backend.

There is another option called "Upgrade" which we wanted to go ahead with as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-upgrading-from-mobile-services/). We have followed all the steps and also generated all our scaffolding code with the node command - "**npm i -g azure-mobile-apps-compatibility**". Now, we only have one doubt i.e. about the Authentication and Authorization.

In our existing Azure Mobile services We have used Custom Authentication using Zumo tokens as mentioned [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Generating_your_own_ZUMO_auth_token_Day_8_.aspx). Client always pass that Zumo token in subsequent requests and Mobile service take cares Authorization for each table operation and API (cutom API) access.

Now our doubt is after generating scaffolding, do we need to do any additional changes in that Authentication and Authorization code i.e. (Zumo Token) or Will it work as it is ? It may be a basic question but if anybody has already gone through this then please guide us to the right path.

I also have one more doubt in my mind i.e. I have migrated one of my Mobile services to app service with the Migrate button click available on Mobile service which requires no code change on client and server. Will my migrated mobile Service (Mobile service which is migrated to Mobile app service with Migrate option and without Upgrade) going to work even after Azure mobile Services shut down after December 2016 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are a little tricky if you are using an identity provider like facebook or twitter, but since you're using custom authentication, it should be fairly straightforward.

You'll need to generate tokens using the `azure-mobile-apps/src/auth` module, as shown in the [custom auth sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/samples/custom-authentication/api/login.js).

You migrated Mobile Service will continue to function as usual after Mobile Services is shut down.

Comment: Thanks Dale for your response. It means that we will have to generate JWT tokens with custom claims that will work with Azure App Service. My existing Zumo token code will not work in that case. Right ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the only requirement for tokens passed to App Service is that they contain a sub claim (subject, or user id). That, and they were signed using the same signing key, of course. You should be able to tweak the existing code to make it work, but the auth module makes generating tokens very easy.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your response.